# Gradle Build Error Evaluating Root Project for org/gradle/internal/metaobject/MethodMixIn

Tags: gradle

I've been playing with a legacy project's build script and I get the following error with Gradle 2.13.

```
myhost jthoms$ gradle clean build
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.13/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/<my-project>/build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'com.mycompany.myorg.myproject'.
> org/gradle/internal/metaobject/MethodMixIn

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.494 secs
```

My `build.gradle` file looks as follows:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'http://<my-nexus-repo>/' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-clover-plugin:2.1.2'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.clover'

// more build stuff below irrelevant to error line.
```

My build fails, so how can this error be fixed?

I worked this error out, but I couldn't find anything related to the class mentioned in the error output, so I thought that I would share my finding here.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this thread](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-clover-plugin/issues/41) for a similar error. In the thread, @bmuschko recommended upgrading to a newer version of Gradle. For me, upgrading from Gradle version 2.13 to 3.5.1 worked like a charm.